# Previewing files so as not to require download

Tags: facebook, ms-office

Facebook has a nice way to preview powerpoint files.. It goes to a microsoft link, e.g. link. You can browse the presentation etc, all very nice and useful for the user and Facebook.

However, I cannot find any sort of API doing that with microsoft.

I found this blog post, which is kindof what I want, but its not referencing any API that I can use to produce this programmatically.

I have a website which users can store files (also powerpoint presentations) and would like them to be able to preview it.

Has anyone got any experience with this? Preferably not going through microsoft route (if possible)..